# TinyDB and Python - get last inserted row

Tags: python, database, tinydb

I am using tinyDB to store some data with python, and I am trying to get the last row that I inserted to the db. so I am doing this:

```
data = db.all() # get all data from db
last_row = data[len(data) - 1]
```

and this is how I get the last row, but it is not so efficient because I am getting all the db at the beginning.

is there a better way doing so?

Comment: Why do you want to get the "last row"?

Comment: @Tomalak because I am saving data from a dynamic page to this db, and I want to check if the data on the page got updated, so I get the last row I inserted to the db, and check if it's not equal -> then there is new data.

Comment: TinyDB doesn't have aggregation so you can't just query for a max, but you can create a sufficient substitute. Store each instance of page data with a time and store when you last fetched. When checking for new data, get when you last fetched, get the page data corresponding to that time, then do your compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `doc_id` for that case since the last row will the largest index

```
last_row = db.get(doc_id=len(db))
```